# FQL Select Posts From Specific Month

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to query the Facebook Graph API using the PHP-SDK. What I'm trying to do is pretty much what is specified in the title: select ALL posts from a specific month of this year.

I've been searching for a while and I can't find a correct syntax to select the posts from a date range.

[Here is an example using a conditional statement](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) with the "created_time" field. I've tried something like this (select the posts from jan 1 2012 to jan 31 2012):

```
SELECT post_id, FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time < 1325394000 AND created_time > 1327986000
```

But this query is only returning the posts from january 31.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you had your times reversed.

[Correct query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20=%20me%28%29%20AND%20created_time%20%3C%201327986000%20AND%20created_time%20%3E%201325394000):

```
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time < 1327986000 AND created_time > 1325394000
```

And use the `LIMIT` functionality to get more posts. The above query with a LIMIT 500 works for me as expected.

Comment: Damn! I shouldn't have drop school... It worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: The 500 limit is resulting in long response times and timeouts, do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Then drop it to what you what is necessary